# VBA Matching opposite sign values in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a matching macro in a column which finds opposite sign values. This is where I stacked:

```
Sub matching()

Dim i As Integer
Dim myVar, myFunc As Variant
Dim myList As Range

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1

myVar = Cells(i, "J")
myList = Range(Cells(2, "J"), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, "J"))
myFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myVar, myList, 1, False)

If myVar - myFunc = 0 Then
Cells(i, "G") = "Match"
Else
Cells(i, "G") = "No Match"

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you don't need to define your list in the loop each time as a tip.  I think myVar = Cells(i, "J") needs to be myVar = 0-Cells(i, "J") then if vlookup returns its found, if not its not, no need for the calc part.  not 100% tho.  I think you are tying to code the formula =if(isna(vlookup(myval,mylist,1,0)),"no match","match")

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by opposite sign value.  Please make it more descriptive.

Comment: I have a list with huge amount of data. The "J" column has values like 1000, 2000, -1000 etc. This list consist of accounting data basically which have debit-credit parts (+1000,-1000 value) . I need to narrow the existing list by find these pairs. The found pairs sum has to be 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

apart from some syntax errors I think your code isn't doing what you'd want it to.

`myVar` will point to some cell of `myList` range. This will have "VLookup" always "catch" the `myVar` cell and myFunc to return `myVar` value and thus resulting in `If myVar - myFunc = 0` check to always return `True`

should you better set your aim, you could adapt the following code to your needs

```
Sub matching2()

Dim myList As Range
Dim mySht As Worksheet

Set mySht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTest") '<== change "SheetTest" to actual name of your sheet

With mySht
    Set myList = .Range("J2:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
    With .Cells(2, "G")
        .Formula = "=if( vlookup($J2," & "J2:J$" & myList.Rows.Count + 1 & ",1,0) - $J2 = 0,""match"",""no match"") "
        .Copy .Resize(myList.Rows.Count)
    End With
End With


End Sub
```

with no loops